# In debug mode, the execution doesn't always stop on my breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, breakpoints

I've got a weird problem in Visual Studio when I execute some **C#** code in debug mode. I set some breakpoints and I execute my code step by step but sometimes, when I press <kbd>F10</kbd>, the execution continues as if I pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> but won't stop on my breakpoints anymore until I compile the solution again.

When I clean the solution and restart my computer, it could fix the problem but it'll eventually reoccur.

Did you ever have this problem and what is the solution?

Comment: Disable incremental linking and edit-and-continue - that usually fixes such problems for C/C++

Comment: @Erik *Edit and Continue* doesn't seem to be the problem. I've never disabled it in years and that has never happened to me.

Comment: I agree this is a strange problem. I assume that when you say you've compiled in "debug" mode, you are also implying that you haven't inadvertently turned *on* optimizations even in debug mode? Do the breakpoint icons in the margin look grayed-out?

Comment: @Oscar Mederos: Edit and Continue for c++ isn't stable - the larger your projects are, the more likely it is that you get strange non-reproducible problems, both runtime issues and strange internal compiler errors.

Comment: The breakpoints icons aren't greyed (nor empty with an exclamation mark). The project configuration is the default one and this problem occurs on different projects. The question could seems stupid but can it be related to an exotic policy in the domain's configuration?

Comment: Erik's right about edit-and-continue not being stable for C++ (also IntelliSense), but that's not really the case in C# or VB.NET. I've never had any problems with it there. I don't think this is a stupid question, but it's definitely one I don't have the answer to. It *could* potentially be an issue with the domain (that is, something related to the privileges assigned to your user account in that domain), or it could be related to a 64-bit version of Windows. Are you 32-bit all the way down and running with Administrator privileges?

Comment: I have a 32bits Windows XP SP3. I'm not running as a local admin but a domain user. I can't fiddle with my privileges while I'm not sysadmin but what can I do to diagnose the problem?